# Render view in code with the proper view mode

Tags: views, 8

I have a view that calls for Show: Content, using a very specific view mode (neither Full content nor Teaser, it's created on purpose and themed according to my needs, basically an e-mail oriented output with very different HTML classes than the usual views displays in Drupal). When used in a page, it renders perfectly. However, when I render it from code to be able to use the resulting HTML directly:

```
$view = Views::getView('view_id');
$view->setDisplay('default');
$view->setArguments($args);
$view->preExecute();
$view->execute();
$render = $view->render();
$html = render($render);
```

I get an otherwise perfect render but not with that view mode, just the usual stuff. Alternative calls do the same:

```
$render = $view->buildRenderable('default', $args);
$html = render($render);
```

How could I force it to render the way I want it?

Comment: which view mode are you trying to display? which view display id are you trying to display?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are using `default` above when it should be another value, whatever your display's machine name is (it's in the Advanced column under Other).

Comment: It's `default` intentionally. These are internal use views that are never rendered normally, neither page nor block, they are only rendered into controllers where they need to appear. But I figured out the reason, I'll add an answer now.

Answer (score 1):

It was the theme. The rendering took place under cron and ran under the administration theme rather than the usual one, meaning different twigs. The solution will be to sub-theme the admin theme to make sure all the relevant twigs are present there, too.